# Count if only of the critieria

Tags: excel, countif

Suppose I wrote this count if formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($B$1:$NA$1,'ALL PP'!$B$1,B11:NA11,"N*",$B$3:$NA$3,"Mon")+COUNTIFS($B$1:$NA$1,'ALL PP'!$B$1,B11:NA11,"Sick",$B$3:$NA$3,"Mon")
```

Suppose one row split into 7 columns (Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday) contains N, then it counts. Then the output would be one

Same goes with with "Sick" the output would be one.

But if "sick" and "goes" on same day it would count as 2. I don't want that. I want a formula that can count either 1 of them.

Comment: What is your excel version? Post some sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a more elegant way of doing it, but you could use an `if` statement:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($B$1:$NA$1,'ALL PP'!$B$1,B11:NA11,"N*",$B$3:$NA$3,"Mon")+COUNTIFS($B$1:$NA$1,'ALL PP'!$B$1,B11:NA11,"Sick",$B$3:$NA$3,"Mon") >= 1, 1, 0)
```